Type hint for descriptor in abstract class/interface
I want to have a class with custom properties defined by descriptor classes and an interface that hides implementation details.
My code currently looks like this. It works, type checkers do not complain, but it looks ugly because of the cast from Ten to int. Intermediate function ten also complicates things if I want the descriptor to be Generic.
from typing import cast

class Ten:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None) -> int:
        return 10

    def __set__(self, obj, value: int) -> None:
        pass  # just to make Ten "writeable"

def ten() -> int:
    return cast(int, Ten())  # <-- this is ugly

class ABase:
    x: int

class A(ABase):
    x: int = ten()


def fn(value: ABase) -> int:
    return value.x


a = A()
print(fn(a))

Is it possible to achieve some level of type checking and no errors from type checkers without using magic hacks like this one?

I'd argue there is a significant difference between an int-valued instance attribute that an instance of ABase should have and the Ten-valued class attribute that A actually has. At least as currently written, nothing in ABase prevents assignment to a.x, but Ten is read-only.

@chepner a descriptor that only defines __get__ does not mean a name is read-only. It  only means that the descriptor will not be involved in writes to that name. For example, functions return methods when accessed on an instance. However, an instance can write to the same name and hide the method/function.

@chepner I'm sorry for bad example, but I'm more concerned about passing the type then solving, if the type is readonly. I'm adding dummy __set__ method to focus on my needs.

Type checkers have trouble with descriptors  do not want to pretend that a descriptor is the thing it will return. If you type ABase.x as a generic descriptor, then mypy (at least) will understand that accesses to the attribute will result in what the descriptor returns. It will even understand how the descriptor may return different results depending on whether the descriptor was accessed on the class or on an instance. eg.
from typing import overload, Callable, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
Value = TypeVar('Value')
ClassValue = TypeVar('ClassValue')

class GenericNonDataDescriptor(Generic[T, Value, ClassValue]):
    def __init__(
        self,
        inst_func: Callable[[T], Value],
        class_func: Callable[[type[T]], ClassValue]
    ) -> None:
        self.inst_func = inst_func
        self.class_func = class_func

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: T, owner: type[T]) -> Value: ...
    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner: type[T]) -> ClassValue: ...
    def __get__(self, instance: T | None, owner: type[T]) -> Value | ClassValue:
        print(f'{instance=} and {owner=}')
        if instance is None:
            return self.class_func(owner)
        else:
            return self.inst_func(instance)

def ten(instance: 'Foo') -> int:
    return 10

def ten_for_class(cls: type['Foo']) -> str:
    return 'called on class'

class MyClass:
    x = GenericNonDataDescriptor(ten, ten_for_class)

reveal_type(MyClass().x) # line 33
reveal_type(MyClass.x)   # line 34

If you call mypy on this file you get:
file.py:33: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
file.py:34: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

Alternative Approaches
As mypy does not like interchanging actual types and the types that a descriptor provides access to, you are not going to be able to make your code example type check cleanly. So aside from changing the type of your x attribute to be a union of "int | Descriptor[int]", what can you actually do?
One answer is to use properties. Mypy and other type checkers have a better understanding of properties, even though they are implemented as (data) descriptors. Using properties (and the abc module) you can get almost the same interface, easy to read typing, and runtime protection from classes that have not defined the required interfaces. This last point is important, as if a class forgets to "override" x, then the type checker will not complain, and the attribute will not be present at runtime.
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def _x(self) -> int: ...

    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return self._x()

class Foo(Base):
    def _x(self) -> int:
        return 10

reveal_type(Foo().x) # line 15
reveal_type(Foo.x)   # line 16

The key difference, is that access to the property via the class will not invoke the property, but return the property itself. Which mypy shows:
file.py:15: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
file.py:16: note: Revealed type is "def (self: file.Base) -> builtins.int"

